# static middle ware in express just doesn't serve files

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

i have the following directory structure

```
/app
   js
   css

/node
   server.js

index.html
dashboard.html
```

I am using

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/../'));
```

for accessing index.html and dashobard.html (in server.js)

The following route works just fine:

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendfile('index.html');
});
```

But this one doesn't work

```
app.get('/dashboard',ensureAuthenticated,function(req,res){
  res.sendfile('dashboard.html');
});
```

I get this

```
Error: ENOENT, stat 'dashboard.html'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can call res.sendfile without express.static**

**For your problem:**

I guess **both** `res.sendfile('index.html')` and `res.sendfile('dashboard.html')` **are not correct**, they should be

```
var root = fs.realpathSync('..');
res.sendfile(path.join(root, 'index.html'))
res.sendfile(path.join(root, 'dashboard.html'));
```

**But why you do not see bug on `app.get('/', ...)`?** 
because it is already handle by static middleware. Note / <==> /index.html.

**About err on /dashboard**
`app.get('/dashboard', ...)` is called and it can not find 'dashboard.html' in `'/node'` folder so the err ENOENT happened.

Comment: express forbids `'..'` in `res.sendfile` and family. Don't know right now if the restriction can be turned off somehow.

Comment: really? how about ./../file.html?

Comment: Same results. Cant use '..' anywhere in the route.

Comment: ../ cannot be used. Its a issue with express and they aren't allowed.

Comment: @bduran I have already researched about it and i agree hundred percent. Do you have any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: Express developers says it's designed like that for security purposes. You can workaround it with `path.resolve` but maybe there are cleaner methods. You can check the API of the path module here: http://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: Oh, i've just tried with express, bduran is right, i updated the code to solve this problem

Comment: @bduran how do you think about '..' in sendfile, is it a bug or express design?

Comment: It work for me, window8, node#0.10.20, express#3.4.6

Comment: i get a path not defined :(